# Нужно получить значения определенного ключа из массива объектов и собрать их в новом массиве JS

Tags: javascript

Требуется помощь =) Не могу разобраться. Получаю массив объектов после POST запроса (ниже пример) :

```
{
  "items": [{
    "encodedId": "1:0JPQqdGM0JNWCdCzf2Jt0LHQotGV0ZUh0ZbRlBXCt0Je0JHQruKAnDcUXkZQ0YvQscKnehLRnNC1KtGK0Ll9BWLigLo/HXXCrhw=",
    "influence": 700.0,
    "similarCount": 3
  }, {
    "encodedId": "1:fmYoHEjQrRbQhz3RiUtm4oCh0JLRmtCLIyU10IzigqzRgGjQmCoR0JFg0YRhwrVzN9CxDUM50KcpdTbRiNCLwpjRkuKAphXRkVxh0JU50K5uWdC50L7RjX0C0KwQRsKp",
    "influence": 607.0,
    "similarCount": 8
  }],
  "mappings": [{
    "inn": "7710137066",
    "entityIds": [534868]
  }]
}
```

После чего нужно сделать из этого объект с массивом(ниже пример), где я получаю значения каждого ключа encodedId и кладу их в массив ids :

```
{
  "ids": [ "1:0JPQqdGM0JNWCdCzf2Jt0LHQotGV0ZUh0ZbRlBXCt0Je0JHQruKAnDcUXkZQ0YvQscKnehLRnNC1KtGK0Ll9BWLigLo/HXXCrhw=",
"1:fmYoHEjQrRbQhz3RiUtm4oCh0JLRmtCLIyU10IzigqzRgGjQmCoR0JFg0YRhwrVzN9CxDUM50KcpdTbRiNCLwpjRkuKAphXRkVxh0JU50K5uWdC50L7RjX0C0KwQRsKp",
  ]
}
```

Создал функцию, чтобы это дело преобразовать, но где-то такой затык, не пойму где. Если поможете готовым ответом будет круто, я буду от него уже смотреть как вы сделали логику.

мой вариант :

```
      const objOfIds = objectSearch.reduce(
        (acc, { encodedId }) => {
          return {
            ids: [...acc.encodedId, encodedId],
          };
        },
        { ids: [] }
      );
      console.log(objOfIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  "items": [{
    "encodedId": "1:0JPQqdGM0JNWCdCzf2Jt0LHQotGV0ZUh0ZbRlBXCt0Je0JHQruKAnDcUXkZQ0YvQscKnehLRnNC1KtGK0Ll9BWLigLo/HXXCrhw=",
    "influence": 700.0,
    "similarCount": 3
  }, {
    "encodedId": "1:fmYoHEjQrRbQhz3RiUtm4oCh0JLRmtCLIyU10IzigqzRgGjQmCoR0JFg0YRhwrVzN9CxDUM50KcpdTbRiNCLwpjRkuKAphXRkVxh0JU50K5uWdC50L7RjX0C0KwQRsKp",
    "influence": 607.0,
    "similarCount": 8
  }],
  "mappings": [{
    "inn": "7710137066",
    "entityIds": [534868]
  }]
};

const data1 = data.items.reduce((acc, {encodedId}) => {
   acc['ids'].push(encodedId);
  return acc;
}, {ids:[]});

console.log(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю воспользоваться другим методом массива. Поскольку тут все явно прослеживается... Вместо объекта будет значение его свойства.

```js
const data = {
  "items": [{
    "encodedId": "1:0JPQqdGM0JNWCdCzf2Jt0LHQotGV0ZUh0ZbRlBXCt0Je0JHQruKAnDcUXkZQ0YvQscKnehLRnNC1KtGK0Ll9BWLigLo/HXXCrhw=",
    "influence": 700.0,
    "similarCount": 3
  }, {
    "encodedId": "1:fmYoHEjQrRbQhz3RiUtm4oCh0JLRmtCLIyU10IzigqzRgGjQmCoR0JFg0YRhwrVzN9CxDUM50KcpdTbRiNCLwpjRkuKAphXRkVxh0JU50K5uWdC50L7RjX0C0KwQRsKp",
    "influence": 607.0,
    "similarCount": 8
  }],
  "mappings": [{
    "inn": "7710137066",
    "entityIds": [534868]
  }]
};
const objOfIds = { ids: data.items.map(o => o.encodedId) }
console.log(objOfIds)
```

Answer (score -1):

У вас 2 банальные ошибки:

1. Вам нужен не сам объект `objectSearch`, а его ключ `items`, т.е. `objectSearch.items`
2. Внутри `reduce` вам нужен массив `ids`, а не `encodedId`, потому что в начальном значении `acc` у вас `{ids:[]}`, а не `{encodedId:[]}`

   ```js
   const data = {
     "items": [{
       "encodedId": "1:0JPQqdGM0JNWCdCzf2Jt0LHQotGV0ZUh0ZbRlBXCt0Je0JHQruKAnDcUXkZQ0YvQscKnehLRnNC1KtGK0Ll9BWLigLo/HXXCrhw=",
       "influence": 700.0,
       "similarCount": 3
     }, {
       "encodedId": "1:fmYoHEjQrRbQhz3RiUtm4oCh0JLRmtCLIyU10IzigqzRgGjQmCoR0JFg0YRhwrVzN9CxDUM50KcpdTbRiNCLwpjRkuKAphXRkVxh0JU50K5uWdC50L7RjX0C0KwQRsKp",
       "influence": 607.0,
       "similarCount": 8
     }],
     "mappings": [{
       "inn": "7710137066",
       "entityIds": [534868]
     }]
   };

   const objOfIds = data.items.reduce((acc, { encodedId }) => {
     return {
       ids: [...acc.ids, encodedId],
     };
   }, {
     ids: []
   });

   console.log(objOfIds);
   ```

Чутка краткий вариант:

```js
const data = {
  "items": [{
    "encodedId": "1:0JPQqdGM0JNWCdCzf2Jt0LHQotGV0ZUh0ZbRlBXCt0Je0JHQruKAnDcUXkZQ0YvQscKnehLRnNC1KtGK0Ll9BWLigLo/HXXCrhw=",
    "influence": 700.0,
    "similarCount": 3
  }, {
    "encodedId": "1:fmYoHEjQrRbQhz3RiUtm4oCh0JLRmtCLIyU10IzigqzRgGjQmCoR0JFg0YRhwrVzN9CxDUM50KcpdTbRiNCLwpjRkuKAphXRkVxh0JU50K5uWdC50L7RjX0C0KwQRsKp",
    "influence": 607.0,
    "similarCount": 8
  }],
  "mappings": [{
    "inn": "7710137066",
    "entityIds": [534868]
  }]
};

const objOfIds = data.items.reduce((acc, { encodedId }) => ({
  ids: [...acc.ids, encodedId]
}), {
  ids: []
});

console.log(objOfIds);
```